# Only update a single row in a query based on non-unique parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big table with duplicate keys that I am trying to connect to smaller table that has unique keys.  I know for a fact there will not matches for everything.  I only want a match from my smaller table to update a single row in the bigger table and then to move onto the next smaller table row for the next update.  I need it like this because I am trying to create unique id's in the larger table as each row represents a real world product which has it's own heiarchy of real world objects.

So for example,

```
bigtable
barcodeSnippet        t_stamp       workId       parentCase    newId
aaaa                  time1         1            1             NULL
aaaa                  time1         1            1             NULL
aaaa                  time1         1            1             NULL
```

and my small table might have this

```
smalltable
id   barcodeSnippet      t_stamp      workId      parentCase
1    aaaa                time1        1           1
2    aaaa                time1        1           1
```

the end result I want in my bigtable is

```
bigtable
barcodeSnippet        t_stamp       workId       parentCase    newId
aaaa                  time1         1            1             1
aaaa                  time1         1            1             2
aaaa                  time1         1            1             NULL
```

where I only mached once per row, and was left over with a NULL since I had 3 rows in the big table and two matches in my smaller one.

My current query

```
UPDATE bigtable as bt
JOIN smallTable as st ON (bt.barcodeSnippet = b.barcodeSnippet AND 
bt.parentCase= st.parentCase and bt.t_stamp = st.t_stamp and bt.workId = 
st.workId)
SET bt.bottlesId = st.id;
```

does not work, and I don't see it's possible to use the LIMIT in a UPDATE for MySQL.  I have seen other answers in MS SQL where you can use `TOP 1`, perhaps where newId IS NULL, but again I am using MySQL here.

I am thinking I might need to use a Stored Procedure/Cursor approach but even with that it seems like I will run into the issue of having to run an update statement and then I am back at square 1.

Any ideas?  Using MySQL 5.6.

EDIT:  Think I have a decent solution.  I just updated with my query so I do have duplicates.  However, now I added a row number column.  I plan to join the table on itself and update it if the row number is < the row number, therefore I keep the top ID and can turn the others to null, which is suitable.

Something like this

```
UPDATE bigtable tb
JOIN bigtable tb2 ON tb.newId = tb2.newId
SET tb.newId = NULL
WHERE tb.rowNumber < tb2.rowNumber;
```

Comment: I question your table design, because you seem to have the same information repeated across two different tables.

Comment: I didn't create the tables I inherited them.  Trust me the design is god awful, its what I have to deal with at the moment.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen. It seams like you are looking for a comlicated way to copy a table.

Comment: The large table contains missing data the small table does not.  I am doing this for a very specific purpose.  Please just take my question at face value and assume I have been working on this for a week and am not a complete dullard and that there is no way around this.  Both tables have many other differing columns.  I am only showing what is actually shared to make my question concise.

Comment: What is the server version? ROW_NUMBER() would be really useful here.

Comment: Also I have another idea.  My UPDATE currently does update everythign so I end up with the case where I have 6 rows with the same id in my big table.  If i could also come up with a query that just turns 5 of those into NULL values, then that is also suitable for what I am doing next with this data.

Comment: Well you need to enumerate the two tables groupwise and use the row numbers for your join. But without window functions its a pain.

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table, and problems like this become unnecessarily tricky

Answer (score 0):

You use the auto_incremented id column with the superglobal `$_GET`:

1.php
`<?php $var = $row["id"]; ?>`
`<a href="2.php?id=<?php echo $var; ?>">Something</a>`

Then in your 2.php

`<?php $id = $_GET["id"];`
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id';";`
Of course you need to use prepared statements